# Recursive method using a graph changes it's state on all levels

Tags: java, recursion

I try to solve a graph problem with a recursive method returning one correct solution but I wonder if it is possible to do so, because changing the state of a graph in one recursion level will change it on other levels since they refer to the same object. Is there any way to solve it?

Here are my code samples:

1) Nodes - here you can see that Nodes are binded creating edges

```
public class Node{

private int visited;                        
private int label;                          
private int order;                          
private int degree;                         
private ArrayList <Node> neighbours;        
...
}
```

2) Graph

```
public class Graph {

private ArrayList <Square> graph;       
private int graphSize;                          
private int numOfVertices;  
...
}
```

3) And the sketch of a method:

```
public boolean backTracking(int label, int moves, Graph graph){     

// something here

if(current.getVisited() != 1){

            // current is a next neighbor of a vertex
            if(backTracking(current.getLabel(),completedMoves, graph))
                return true;
}

return false;
```

Comment: Generally speaking, there are two ways to implement backtracking: (1) when you backtrack, undo any changes that were made when you went forward; (2) make only modifications you can cheaply discard when you backtrack, for instance by copying the data at each step that might need to be reversed, or by tracking the state of the algorithm separately from the state of the data structure.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your "graph problem" is, but if you need to track additional information per level then use a stack (push when going down a level, pop when going up).

If you need to store additional information per node then you can either place it inside Node class, or hold it in a Map. You can also clean entries in the map while backtracking.